# R: selecting subset without copying

Tags: r, immutability, subset, apply, copy-on-write

Is there a way to select a **subset** from objects (data frames, matrices, vectors) **without making a copy** of selected data?

I work with quite large data sets, but never change them. However often for convenience I select subsets of the data to operate on. Making a copy of a large subset each time is very memory inefficient, but both normal indexing and `subset` (and thus `xapply()` family of functions) create copies of selected data. So I'm looking for functions or data structures that can overcome this issue.

Some possible approaches that may fit my needs and hopefully are implemented in some R packages:

- **copy-on-write** mechanism, i.e. data structures that are copied only when you add or rewrite existing elements;
- **immutable data structures**, that only require recreating indexing information for the data structure, but not its content (like making substring from the string by only creating small object that holds length and a pointer to the same char array);
- **`xapply()`** analogues that do not create subsets.

Comment: I think you should look at the `data.table` package (someone will presumably show up here shortly to give you more details ...)

Comment: The database interfaces are clearly what you should be investigating. Pretty much every thing in r is pass-by-promise which becomes effectively pass-by-value at the moment anything needs to be done to the subset.

Comment: @BenBolker: thanks, `data.table` seems to be nice package, but unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs in most cases. In particular, `data.table` has another indexing model and makes it much harder (and slower) to perform selection like `data[1:50, 1:10]` (i.e. selection by both - row & column) and many linear algebra operations. I was thinking of using matrices instead of my data frames to save both space and time, but matrices have their limitations too, so I'm looking for alternative options too.

Comment: @DWin: concerning "pass-by-value". Do you mean that R uses lazy evaluation? But it doesn't correspond to what I see: code `DF <- data[1:10000, ]` takes about 30 seconds, which is much longer than is needed to create promise object. Also this means that data structures have to be permanent not to break language semantics, but they are not. Can you explain it, please? I definitely miss something. (Let me know if it's worth to post it as a separate question.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by permanent. It's perfectly possible to create an object inside a function's environment and have it automatically become garbage-collectible on exit. My understanding is that R does use lazy evaluation. You can use the `delayedAssign` and the `force` functions if you want some control over this.process. Most of us do not think much about it (until it bites us during function evaluations.)

Comment: @DWin: permanent data structures are those that can't be modified in-place. If you want to update it, you have to create a modified copy (that normally shares most elements with original data structure). Thanks for this lazy evaluation stuff - I came from functional programming and things like promises and force make programming in R even more pleasure!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try package [ref](http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/web/packages/ref/index.html). Specifically, its `refdata` class.

What you might be missing about `data.table` is that when grouping (`by=` parameter) the subsets of data are not copied, so that's fast. [Well technically they are but into a shared area of memory which is reused for each group, and copied using memcpy which is much faster than R's for loops in C.]

`:=` in `data.table` is one way to modify a `data.table` in place.  `data.table` departs from usual R programming style in that it is *not* copied-on-write. User has to call `copy()` explicitly to copy a (potentially very large) table, even within a function.

You're right that there isn't a mechanism like `refdata` built into `data.table`. I see what you mean and it would be a nice feature. `refdata` should work on a `data.table`, though, and you might be fine with `data.frame` (but be sure to monitor copies with `tracemem(DF)`).

There is also `idata.frame` (immutable `data.frame`) in package `plyr` you could try.